# Getting javascript errors on iOS and not elsewhere

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, undefined

I'm using a simple jquery script to hide a submenu, append a div to a top level navigation that acts as a button, that will slide toggle that sub-menu on click. It's working on all major browsers I've tried, and my android phone without any issues.
However, I'm getting an error when I try it on an iOS device (testing on two different iPhone versions and an iPhone emulator) which is not allowing the script to run.

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

I am very confused as to why I am only seeing this error on an iOS device, and thanks to their lovely debug console I have no clue where this error is occurring. Any clue as to why this would be happening?

Comment: Have you tried it in Safari on your computer? If it fails there too it would make debugging a lot easier.

Comment: I have, it does work in Safari, Opera, Firefox, Chrome and IE 8+